# undefined method `article_name' .................NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
     @articles = Article.all
    end
    def show
     @article = Article.find(params[ :id])
    end
    def new
    @article = Article.new
    end
    def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
        if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
    else
     render 'new'
    end
    end

    private
     def article_params
           params.require(:article).permit(:Article_name,:enter_text)
    end
end
```

Comment: can you edit your question using code {} around your class Articles ..

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
..... .permit(:name, :enter_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the class name and just specify the value name.
See the example below.

```
   private
     def article_params
           params.require(:article).permit(:name, :enter_text)
    end
```